# Why are there different values for input?

Tags: c++, io, cin

why does when enter 'q' ( or any char)

```
double x;

x = cin.get();

cout << x << endl;
```

return the char value for the character entered, but

```
    double x;

    cin >> x;

    cout << x << endl;
```

returns a random value for 'q'

Answer (score 4):

Like you say, [`std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) gets a *character* from the input stream. For example, if you enter the digit `1` as input, it returns the ASCII code for the character `'1'` which is `49` decimal (on systems that use ASCII, which is almost everything).

When you use the input operator `>>` that function reads and *parses* the input into the correct format. So if you use `>>` with a `double` variable, and enter `1` you will get the value `1.0` in the variable.

The problem you have is that when the input operator `>>` can't properly parse the input, like when you enter a letter instead of a digit, then the input operator will fail and *not* set the variable, meaning you print an uninitialized variable which is *undefined behavior*. Note that this behavior changed in C++11 (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379073/440558)).

You have to remember that a stream object can be used as a condition, and that the input operator function returns the stream in question. So you can do e.g.

```
if (std::cin >> x)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Error in input\n";
```

Comment: +1, with a minor nitpick: `1.0` is representable exactly in a `double` (or a `float`, for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

`std::get()` reads input as *unformatted* integral value, so it succeeds as it doesn't have to format what it reads into any *specific* type. But `operator>>` reads input as *formatted* data, so it has to format what it reads into the given type. Since in your case, the input `'q'` is not suitable for `double`, the formatting fails.