# C++ manipulators

Tags: c++, manipulators

I have started learning *C++* and I think the language is great, but few things are baffling me while I am on my path learning it. In this example:

```
cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed) << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);
```

In this example why do we type the whole `setiosflags(ios::...)` when the program still does the same if I only type `showpoint` without `setiosflags`?

Second question I have is simple. If we have the following:

```
int x=0;
cin>>x;
```

Why do we define a value for `int` if we later change it to something different than `0`?

Comment: You don't need to initialize `x` if you're going to change it to something else before using it. Some people just like to initialize all variables out of habit.

Comment: Question #2 depends on whether you're pre-C++11 or post.

Comment: Regarding the first question, it's because [`std::showpoint` is a standard manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). As for the second question, see e.g. [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378989/why-does-stringstream-change-value-of-target-on-failure/13379073#13379073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do we type the whole`setiosflags(ios::...)`when the program still does the same if I only type `showpoint` without `setiosflags`?

We don't, unless we want the program to be more verbose than necessary. As you say, streaming `setioflags` with a single flag is equivalent to streaming the flag itself. You might use `setioflags` if you have a pre-computed set of flags you want to set.

> Why do we define a value for `int` if we later change it to something different than `0`?

Again, we don't, unless we like unnecessary verbiage. But it's a good habit to initialise variables, to avoid undefined behaviour if you later change the code to assume it has been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Its optional and flexibility language provide, so either you can set manipulators using `setiosflgas` or as showing below:

```
float y= 1.45;
std::cout << std::fixed<<std::showpoint<<y;
```

Why insisting to initialize variables is because before C++11 these uninitialized variables can hold garbage value until you set value for them. And it may create unwanted issues and bugs. So better practice always initialize variables when you define it.

Since C++11 all fundamental data types are initialized to zero if you use explicit constructor as follows:

```
int i2 = int(); // initialized with zero 
int i3{}; // initialized with zero (since C + + 11)
```

Comment: *Since C++11 all basic data types are initialized to zero* [citation needed]

Comment: Not true that basic types are initialised to zero in C++11.   They are in some circumstances (e.g. statics) but not others.

Comment: @Peter condition is added and answer is clarified

Answer (score -1):

1. The stream manipulator `std::setiosflags(ios_base::fmtflags mask)`- is a function  that sets the format flags specified by parameter `mask`. It can be used for multiple flags simultaneously, by using *binary AND* : `&`. It probably exists to provide full/complete functionality of the class that belongs to. Now regarding your question:

> If you can access a flag(member) directly, why bother using a function(setter)?

I can't think of any reason why you shouldn't. However have in mind that `manipulators` are global functions and these constants, `ios_base::fmtflags`, are member constants. For more information on manipulators [check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/).

2. Regarding the second question: you initialize a variable when you define it to avoid undefined behaviour in case you use it, by mistake, before assigning it any value. Local variables need initialization, global variables are initialized   by default.

Comment: binary AND is &, not |.