# atof and stringstream produce different results

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, stringstream, atof

I have been looking into a problem whereby I am converting a float to a human readable format, and back. Namely a string. I have ran into issues using stringstream and found that atof produces "better" results.

Notice, I do not print out the data in this case, I used the debugger to retrieve the values:

```
    const char *val = "73.31";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val << '\0';
    float floatVal = 0.0f;
    ss >> floatVal; //VALUE IS 73.3100052

    floatVal = atof(val); //VALUE IS 73.3099976
```

There is probably a reasonable explanation to this. If anybody can enlighten me I'd be greatful :).

Comment: The `<< '\0'` is redundant.

Comment: Depending on if you're compiling in C++11 mode or not, the stream input operator `>>` uses either `strtod` or `scanf` to parse the number. That may make some difference from using `atof`. (See e.g. [this old answer of mine for links to references](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379073/440558))

Comment: [Not reproducible one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9912ab957d793d3c) and [two](http://pastebin.com/qfnYFxE0)

Comment: With `GCC 5.1.1` I get the same value with both (73.3099976), using either `C++11` or `C++03`.

Comment: @n.m. Reproducable with MSV2015: `73.3100051879883`, `73.3099975585938`

Comment: `basic_istream` has an `operator>>(float& _Val)` which at some point uses `extern _CRTIMP2_PURE float __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Stofx(const char *,
 _Out_opt_ _Deref_post_opt_valid_ char **,
 long, int *);. Meanwhile `atof` returns a `double` and not a float value. `atof`returns a correct value of `73.31` which is then changed to `73.3099975585938` when converting `double` to `float`. **MSVC2015**

Comment: What platform and compiler do you use?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that. MSVC2013

Comment: With MSVC2013 i get a warning: floatVal = std::atof(val); Conversion from double to float. It might be the same on your platform. I fi Change the float to a double, there is no warning and no difference.

Comment: we can safely cast to a float in this case, no?

Comment: If you cast from double to float you loose precision. That is the point here.

Comment: This seems to be introduced in vc11. No difference in vc10.

Comment: floating point arithmetics, they are not so accurate as you may think

Comment: 73.31 converts to 73.30999755859375 as a float (http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ ), and rounded to 9 digits that's 73.3099976. So what you get from atof() is correct, despite double rounding (from string to double and then double to float).

Comment: And conversion through stringstream has issues; see http://www.exploringbinary.com/incorrect-round-trip-conversions-in-visual-c-plus-plus/ and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1540816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer is based on the assumption that OP uses MSVC**

`atof` is indeed better in reading floating point values than `istream`.

See this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const char *val = "73.31";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    float floatVal = 0.0f;
    ss >> floatVal;
    std::cout << "istream>>(float&)                       :" << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << floatVal << std::endl;

    double doubleVal = atof(val);
    std::cout << "double atof(const char*)                :" << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << doubleVal << std::endl;

    floatVal = doubleVal;
    std::cout << "(float)double atof(const char*)         :" << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << floatVal << std::endl;

    doubleVal = floatVal;
    std::cout << "(double)(float)double atof(const char*) :" << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << floatVal << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
istream>>(float&)                       :  73.3100051879883
double atof(const char*)                :             73.31
(float)double atof(const char*)         :  73.3099975585938
(double)(float)double atof(const char*) :  73.3099975585938
```

The compiler even warns about the conversion from `double`to `float` this:

```
warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

I also found this page: [Conversions from Floating-Point Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3d6fhea.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

**Update:**

The value `73.3099975585938` seems to be the correct `float` interpretation of the `double` value `73.31`.

---

**Update:**
`istream>>(double&)` works correctly as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const char *val = "73.31";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    double doubleVal = 0.0f;
    ss >> doubleVal;
    std::cout << "istream>>(double&) :" << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << doubleVal << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
istream>>(double&) :             73.31
```

---

For arithmetic types `istream::operator>>` uses `num_get::get`.
`num_get::get` should be using something like `scanf("%g")` for `float` [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get)

BUT:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>


int main()
{
    std::string s = "73.31";
    float f = 0.f;
    sscanf(s.c_str(), "%g", &f);
    std::cout << std::setw(18) << std::setprecision(15) << f << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
73.3099975585938
```

For me this looks like there might be a bug in Microsoft `num_get`

Comment: i tested this code on gcc, clang and vc. And the only explanation that i see is the implementation of  istream>>float. Looks like VC does it right (using float) while all the others use double and then convert result to float.

Comment: @Alexander It's not clear why you deem the VC implementation "right". It does not convert the decimal number to its closest binary representation, while all others do.

Comment: Why would you say that "the real culprit is the cast from double to float"? The bad case is the istream `>>` extraction. `atof` followed by cast delivers correct results, `>>` does not.

Comment: so what do u expect from stream>>float? we have several options: 1. read into double then convert to float. 2. read into long double and convert to float 3. read into float directly. What is the right way?

Comment: @n.m. "It does not convert the decimal number to its closest binary representation, while all others do"
Is that so? When you look at your tests you will see that gcc evaluates to `73.3099975585938`. So the cast after `atof` is correct.

Comment: Yes, the cast after atof is correct, but you sre calling it "the culprit" as if it's guilty of something.

Comment: BTW float f = 73.3f; f += 0.01f; // gives 73.3100051879883.

Comment: Yeah, my wording isn't the best here. I'm already thinking about how to rephrase it.