# C++ working with files, having trouble making a program

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a simple program that can continously add data to a .txt document. Take a look at my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    ofstream playersW("players.txt");
    ifstream playersR("players.txt");

    int id;
    string name, info = "";
    float money;

    while (playersR >> id >> name >> money) {
        if (playersR.is_open()) {
            info += to_string(id) + " " + name + " " + to_string(money) + "\n";
        }
    }

    playersW << info;

    playersR.close();

    cout << "Enter player ID, Name and Money (or press 'CTRL+Z' + 'Enter' to quit):" << endl;

    while (cin >> id >> name >> money) {
        if (playersW.is_open()) {
            playersW << id << " " << name << " " << money << endl;
        }
    }

    playersW.close();
}
```

What I want is the program to first read the data that is stored in **players.txt** and then write it again and also add the new additional data to **players.txt**.

**EDIT:** With the code I have now, my program **only** writes in the file **players.txt** the new information that the user enters.

Comment: What does your program do right now?

Comment: Why not open the ofstream in append mode ?

Comment: why making such big string to store all the data? also include class string

Comment: Two streams for the same file? Not a great idea. Just use append mode?

Comment: @Raindrop7: We include headers, not classes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  know I mean `<string>`

Comment: `if (playersR.is_open())` is redundant

Comment: Can anyone post this as a answer please? Also, why should I include string? All my programs work just fine without including string. I think (from what I've read so far, that now string is included in iostream), so can you point out a reason or a simple program which is not going to work without including string?

Comment: @S.A.: It "works" by pure chance. It may not tomorrow, or on a different OS, or a different version of your compiler, or a different compiler. Simply include the proper headers. Period! It only takes a very brief moment to fix.

Comment: You can apply these suggestions to your code and write your own answer. I'm going to the pub. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Enjoy!

Comment: Can you write to a new file and, once complete, delete the old file and rename your new file? It is a bad idea to operate on the same file with two streams as you are.

Comment: Okay, I will include string in every program since now! Also, the problem is that I don't know how to apply the suggestions, because I don't understand that. I guess I am just going to find some tutorials on working with files :),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple program that can open the file `players.txt` in binary mode so it first reads the content and displays it then it asks the user to input new players until the user enters `0` or negative player `id` so the loop breaks and then it closes the file to save the new appended content:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

    fstream players("players.txt");

    int id;
    string name, info = "";
    float money;

    while (players >> id >> name >> money)
        cout << name << "   " << id << "   "  << money << endl;

    players.clear();
    players.seekp(0, ios::end);

    cout << "Enter player ID, Name and Money (or press 'CTRL+Z' + 'Enter' to quit):" << endl;

    while(1)
    {
        cout << "id: "; 
        cin >> id;
        cout << endl;

        if(!cin || id <= 0)
            break;

        cout << "name: ";
        cin >> name;
        if(!cin)
            break;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "money: ";
        cin >> money;
        if(!cin)
            break;
        cout << endl;

        players << id << "   " << name << "   " << money << endl;
    }

    players.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(id <= 0) // if so break` Insufficient. You don't ever check for success of the stream operations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: please explain

Comment: What happens when the end of the stream is reached? Or when "invalid" data is found in it? How will your loop be terminated? Are you [assuming C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379073/560648)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes for sure for example a string instead of float so do you recommend exception handling?

Comment: Eh, no... check the stream state. Like you do with _any_ stream operations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: like `if(players.good())` inside the loop?

Comment: No, as you read from `cin`, check `cin`. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: @Raindrop7, your solution works just fine for me, Thank You! By the way, @ Lightness Races In Orbit, weren't you going to the pub?? :). Happy New Year to both of you!

Comment: It doesn't work just fine. It has several critical bugs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I am sorry I meant checking cin not fstream players object

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you mean `while(cin >> id >> name >> money)` then inside loop check for exit value?

Comment: No, you can't do that if you want your prompts. A few `if (!cin) break` would do, no?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: now is it good or are there any other bugs? I tried it for a failing case and works ine breaking the loop

Comment: It's better now in the sense of error checking `cin`. I haven't checked for other bugs. BTW you will need more than just _one_ testcase to verify your new checks.

Comment: Okay, mister @LightnessRacesinOrbit, should I copy-paste my comment from above now? Or not yet?

Comment: Wait how does his program run fine, when there are no {} on the first while ?

Comment: @S.A. the first while has only one statement that is why I removed `{}`

Comment: Aha. So actually the only thing that I was missing was the moving of the pointer to the end of the document. However, I learned to use fstream isntead of both ofstream and ifstream. EDIT: and I guess i missed other small stuff... But however I now know how to do it :)!

Comment: Now you're getting it